# How to Return CloseableHttpResponse?

Tags: java, sockets, http, socket.io

I have a method named `getResponse()` in my program:

```
public ClosableHTTPResponse getResponse()
{

        RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(120 * 1000).build();

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = null;
        CloseableHttpResponse response = null;


        try {
            httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();
            HttpGet httpPostRequest = new HttpGet(getURL);
            httpPostRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "Token " + APIKey);
            httpPostRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");


            response = httpClient.execute(httpPostRequest);
            String statusLine = response.getStatusLine().toString();
            System.out.println("Status Line Response: " + statusLine);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (response != null) response.close();
            if (httpClient != null) httpClient.close();
        }


        return response;
    }

}
```

When I call this method from external method in the following code:

```
public void analzyeReponseA()
{

        CloseableHttpResponse response = null;

    try {
        response = getResponse("p1", "p2");

        String OKResponse = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK";
                        String statusLine = response.getStatusLine().toString();

            if (statusLine.contains(OKResponse)) {

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

             // java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed exception thrown on next line..
            String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
            System.out.println("Response String:\n" + responseString);

   }

}
```

I'm getting a `java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed` exception
on this line:

```
String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31659073) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16798389) thread, presumably this is happening bec I call    `if (response != null) response.close();` in `getResponse()` method (*correct?*)

If so, my question now is how do I return a `CloseableHttpResponse` without the program throwing above exception? Is the only option to call        `String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");` in `getReponse()` method and return a `responseString` instead of `CloseableHttpResponse`? What if I still want to access the `response` object in caller code (like to check status line or something else)?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, I'd first look to see if the code really needed to return an `HttpResponse`. If the method(s) that call `getResponse()` all only need, e.g, the contents, then return the contents rather than the response.

Otherwise, you should be able to do, using the try-with-resources approach:

```
public void callingMethod() {
  try (CloseableHttpResponse resp = getResponse();) {
  {
      // example
      HttpEntity entity = resp.getEntity();
  }
}
```

And remove the close from the `getResponse()` method.

Also, you do not want to be opening/closing the HttpClient on each invocation. That class is designed to be used multiple times. There is more information at [You're Using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/). Thus, you may wish to refactor the code to move the `HttpClient` elsewhere.